# pickadate.js disable second Saturday or disable Saturday of any selected week in a month

Tags: jquery, calendar, pickadate

How do I disable a day of a particular week using pickadate.js? For example, let's say 2nd and 4th Saturdays should be disabled and Monday of the 3rd week of the month should be disabled. How do I do that? right now I am just able to disable the total Sundays or Saturdays in a month.

```
$("[name=date]").pickadate({
    multidate: true,
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    hiddenPrefix: 'time_',
    hiddenSuffix: '',
    min: timeoffDate,
    max: to_date,
    disable: disableArray,
    onSet: function onSet(date) {
        if (_.isNull(date.clear)) {
          return requery();
        }
        if (!date.select) {
          return;
        }
        var fromDate = moment(new Date(date.select));
        $("[name=date]").val(fromDate.format("MMM DD, YYYY"));
      }
  });


$.each(workSchedule,function(key,val){
    if($.inArray(key, dayArray) !== -1 && val == '0'){

        var val = parseInt(dayArray.indexOf(key)) + 1;
        disableArray.push(val);
        console.log(key);
    }
});

$.each(holidays,function(k,v){
    disableArray.push(new Date(v.holidayDate));
});
```

> https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#disable-dates-use-arrays

In `disablearray` i have given the number for the week as 0 for Sunday and all the dates in Sunday are disabled and I have also added the holidays' Dates in that array and all those are disabled but now I want to disable Saturday for only 2nd and 3rd week. I couldn't find a way to do that after searching for it.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have right now.